# require js defining modules in html script tags

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to define a module for the initual configuration options of my app inside an script tag in my html. but I get the following error:

```
Error: Module name "options" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

here is the html:

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js" data-main="/Recruiter/temp-search/App/main"></script>
<script> 

    define('options',['jquery'],function($) {        
        return options = {
            salesPhoneNumber : '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SalesPhoneNumber")',
            saleInfoMessage : "To access Temp Search candidate details, please call our team on " + salesPhoneNumber,
            subscriptionInfo : @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.AccessInfo ?? null)),
            questionProLink: src="@(Request.Url.Scheme)://www.questionpro.com/a/TakeSurvey?id=@(Model.IsRecCon ? AppSettings.SurveyRecConId : AppSettings.SurveyOthersId)&amp;custom1=@Model.RecruiterEmail&amp;custom2=@Model.RecruiterId",
            surveyEnabled: '@AppSettings.FlexSurveyEnabled',
            whatsNewUrl: '@AppSettings.UrlWhatsNew',
            salesPhoneNumber:salesPhoneNumber,
            showSaleInfo: '@ViewBag.ShowSaleInfo',
            fileDownloadFailCookieName:'@AppSettings.FileDownloadFail',
            urls: {
                signInUrl: '@string.Format("https://{0}/recruiter/account/signIn", Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host)',
                signInTempsHome: '/recruiter/temp-search/home',
                signInTempsSearch: '/recruiter/temp-search/api/temps',
                checkAvailabilityUrl: '/recruiter/temp-search/api/availability',
                searchUrl: '/recruiter/temp-search/api/temps/search',
                accesslimitUrl: '/recruiter/temp-search/api/ecruiters/accessinfo',
                previewUrl: '/recruiter/temp-search/api/temps/preview'
            },
            elements: {
                signInRegisterDialog: $("#signInRegisterDialog"),
                noSubscriptionDialog: $("#noSubscriptionDialog"),
                searchForm: $("#searchForm"),
                searchKeywords: $("#Keywords"),
                searchLocation: $("#Location"),
                searchRadius: $("#Radius"),
                searchSortBy: $("#sortBy"),
                searchTemp: $("#Temporary"),
                searchContract: $("#Contract"),
                searchPayRateFrom: $("#PayRateFrom"),
                searchPayRateTo: $("#PayRateTo"),
                searchAvailability: $("#AvailabilityConfirmed"),
                locationErrorMsg: $("#locationErrorMsg"),
                checkAll: $(".checkAll"),
                checkCandidate: $(".checkCandidate"),
                availability: {
                    availabilityBtn: $("#availabilityBtn"),
                    availabilityDialog: $("#availabilityDialog"),
                    additionalInformation: $("#AdditionalInformation"),
                    jobPosition: $("#JobPosition"),
                    jobLocation: $("#JobLocation"),
                    payRate: $("#JobPayRateFrom"),
                    payRateTo: $("#JobPayRateTo"),
                    startOn: $("#StartOnDate"),
                    duration: $("#Duration"),
                    checkAvailabilityForm: $("#checkAvailabilityForm"),
                    availabilityLocation: $("#checkAvailabilityForm #JobLocation"),
                    candidateIds: $("#CandidateIds"),
                    tempJobId: $("#TempJobId"),
                    msgPanel: $("#msgPanel"),
                    msg: $(".msg"),
                    errorAvailability: $("#availabilityError"),
                    availabilityConfirmationDialog: $("#availabilityConfirmationDialog"),
                    infoBubbleMessage : $("#infoBubbleMessage"),
                    availabilityConfirmationMsg: $("#availabilityConfirmationDialog .msgDialog"),
                    downloadInfoLink : $("#downloadInfoLink")
                },
                preview: {
                    previewBtn: $('.previewBtn')

                },
                messagePanel: $("#messagePanel")
            },
            minWageRate : @Constants.Range.ApprenticeshipsPerHourMin,
            authentication : @(Request.IsAuthenticated.ToString().ToLower()),
            minDate: '@String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", DateTime.Now)',
            pageInfo: {
                number: @Model.Results.PageNumber,
                size: @Model.Results.PageSize,
                resultsCount: @Model.TotalResultsCount
            },
            criteria : @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Criteria)),
            remainingAccessLimit: @Model.AccessInfo.Remaining,
            totalAccessLimit: @Model.AccessInfo.Limit,
            availableCandidates: @Model.AvailableCandidates,
            candidates: @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Results ?? Model.Results.ToJSON()))
        };
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the code you show in your question but with how you ask RequireJS to load your module. The error message you show happens when you do a `require` call of this form:

```
var foo = require('foo');
```

This kind of `require` call does not work *unless* `foo` is already loaded, and to ensure it is already loaded you can manually load it yourself, or you can have RequireJS do it for you. However, to get RequireJS to do it for you, you need to write your code in a certain way. If you want a module to use `foo` and you want to use the `require` above then, you should do:

```
define(function (require) {
    var foo = require('foo');
    ...
});
```

Or if you need to use `module` and `exports`, the callback can be `function (require, exports, module) {...`.

Also, you should perform the following operations in this order:

1. Load RequireJS.
2. Execute `define('options', ...`.
3. **Then and only then** start loading your application.

This means removing `data-main` and using an explicit `require` call after `define('options'`.